# Laravel order results by column on polymorphic table

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

## Short question

Using Laravel's Eloquent models; how do I order a query by a column on a has `morphMany` polymorphic relationship?

## Longer question

Say I have the given table structure:

```
// table: images
+ -- + ------------ + -------------- + ----- + ----------- +
| id | imageable_id | imageable_type | views | upload_date |
+ -- + ------------ + -------------- + ----- + ----------- +
| 1  | 1            | User           | 100   | 2016-16-06  |
| 2  | 3            | User           | 200   | 2016-16-06  |
+ -- + ------------ + -------------- + ----- + ----------- +

// table: users
+ -- + ---- +
| id | name |
+ -- + ---- +
| 1  | Bob  |
| 2  | Kat  |
+ -- + ---- +
```

...and I have an Eloquent `User` model with a `morphMany` polymorphic relationship.

**How can I order users by the number of views the image they uploaded today receives?**

I have experimented with this issue myself and haven't been able to find a solution. The closest I had come to the correct ordering was when I used a similar query to this:

```
User::with([
   'images' => function ($query) {
       $query->where('upload_date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
           ->orderBy('views', 'DESC');
   }
])->get();
```

But, after trying this, it was evident to me that the users are now incorrectly ordered by their incrementing id, not the `views` column on the `images` table.

Thank you in advance to anybody who helps me on my journey to figuring this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to a comment on this post http://laravel.io/forum/02-21-2014-order-and-paginate-a-collection-by-a-releted-field-using-eloquent.

```
User::leftJoin('images', function ($join) {
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'images.imageable_id')
        ->where('imageable_type', '=', 'User')
        ->where('upload_date', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
})
    ->orderBy('images.views')
    ->select(['players.*']);
```

I tried something similar to this before but was encountering problems because the ids, and other columns, were clashing between the two joined tables. The difference this time being `->select(['users.*'])`. Now, only the user's data is returned.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can also use collections' [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortby) method.

```
$users = User::with([
   'images' => function ($query) {
       $query->where('upload_date', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
   }
])->get()->sortByDesc(function ($user) {
    return $user->images->views;
});
```