# Laravel Polymorphic Relationships with order by

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, relational

Laravel version 7.2.5.

I am using `Polymorphic Relationships` to store the `access logs (login, logout)` for multi-role application.

The data storing part is working completely fine. Now, I need to show the list of records in `desc` format with pagination. But, It's loading the data in the `asc` format

SomeModel.php

```php
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Polymorphic Relationships
     */
    public function loginLog()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(LoginLog::class, 'employable');
    }

    public function show($token)
    {
        return self::where([
            'token' => $token,
        ])->with([
            'loginLog:employable_id,ip,created_at,updated_at'
        ])->first() ?? null;
    }
}
```

I did find the solution. But, somehow it doesn't feel the appropriate way to solve this issue.

Here is the link [Laravel order results by column on polymorphic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852995/laravel-order-results-by-column-on-polymorphic-table)

Comment: have tried `latest()` helper .?

Comment: Thanks @KamleshPaul, its working. I'll put the final code to make it easy for others. Thanks again :)

Comment: please consider mark my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```php
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Polymorphic Relationships
     */
    public function loginLog()
    {
        return $this
            ->morphMany(LoginLog::class, 'employable')
            ->latest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this issue...

```php
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Polymorphic Relationships
     */
    public function loginLog()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(LoginLog::class, 'employable');
    }

    public function show($token, $pagination = 0)
    {
        return self::where([
            'token' => $token,
        ])->with([
            'loginLog' => function ($query) use ($pagination) {
                return $query->select([
                    'employable_id',
                    'ip',
                    'created_at',
                    'updated_at',
                ])
                ->skip($pagination)
                ->take(\Common::paginationLimit())
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
            }
        ])
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->first('id') ?? null;
    }
}
```

Since I do not need the base table's parameters, therefore, I am fetching only `id` from it.

Also, with this way I am able to use the pagination too (I am using `loadmore` pagination).